# Is required to re-verify a captcha after a failed login?

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha

I'm login an account with wrong credentials with re-captcha verification and after a failed login i  login with correct credentials and re captca throws error "Captcha could not be verified".

I verified the recaptcha on first attempt but it throws an error. Please anyone tell me, is required to re-verify a captcha?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As per my suggestion, On your every attempt of login captcha verification is must, whether you failed previous login attempt or success.
You need to verify captcha on every login attempt.

Comment: You could set a session variable saying if reCaptcha was verified or not. If it was, then you could simply remove the reCaptcha and verification on the second attempt.

Comment: like @bert H said below, you need to reverify captcha for every login attempt, failed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once used to verify, a generated correct recaptcha code will be invalidated.
Therefore, each attempt will require a new recaptcha code.

If you like, have a look at [invisible recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) as this might be less intrusive for the user. Invisible recaptcha only gives the user a challange when it isn't sure it's a regular user, for example after multiple submits. So most users will be validated without a challenge.